# WorldServer - Why items are not undo checkout while cancelling the project?

Tags: 2011, worldserver

We come across an issue that on WorldServer, content authors raised a set of components for translation. After some time, they encountered some error (Sorry I don't know the exact error) and they decided to cancel the project.

All the components which are checked-out by WS, while cancelling the project those components are not undo checkout.

I came to know that if there is no error, user decides to cancel the project then WS will do undo checkout properly. That's good and that's what we want.

But problem is at the time of error occurred, it's unable to do undo checkout. Due to this a large set of components (in multiples of 100's components) are checked out by WS.

> **What would be the reason?**

Comment: "it's unable to do undo checkout" - I guess Tridion will have logged something about this?

Comment: @NunoLinhares: You mean on event viewer or some other tridion logs.

Comment: First guess: Event Viewer. If there's a serious error Tridion logs there. There's not many reasons why an undo checkout can fail. I actually can't think of one right now

Comment: "After some time, they encountered some error" - Can you provide more details/steps on this? What do authors do before error occurs? Does the error occur while retrieving translated content, so the project (job) gets 'Error Retrieving' state?

Answer (score 4):

Since Translation Manager 3.0 (2011) `CancelTerminatedJobsInterval` element is removed from the `TranslationManager.xml`. `PurgeJobDaysOld` specifies the number of days after which Completed *and Cancelled* Jobs are purged from Queue.
So, if your job falls in 'Error Retrieving' state your Tridion items won't be undo checked-out automatically because user may want to:
1) Retry Retrieving (in case if the business rule violations are fixed on the translation system/Tridion side, or network problems, etc.);
2) Retry Sending (creating a new project using the same job).
If you want to undo check-out those items, then deleting the job should make it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Double check the [CancelTerminatedJobsInterval settings per SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_TranslationManager_20_SP2/concept_FD0FAF7BD247425EB2D7D47059062B67) ([requires login.](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

Looks like the `TranslationManager.xml` (under `%TRIDION_HOME%\config`) controls when the CMS checks for cancelled jobs to undo things like item check out.

```
<CancelTerminatedJobsInterval>86400</CancelTerminatedJobsInterval>
```

The documentation recommends setting this to no lower than 86400 seconds (or a day), but you could do as low as 5 minutes (300 seconds). Maybe try a lower setting?

If that doesn't work, definitely reach out to Support. You can also delete the translation job to try again, [especially if there's an error](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_TranslationManager_20_SP2/concept_1CB0C52CC81F4A7A9A7EFAD19EFA451C).